# Pandas - convert to float

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column where many of the values has double dot structure. e.g. `0.00076181.1`.

I would like to convert them into a normal float64 value.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What is algorithm for this task? What is expected output for input `0.00076181.1`?

Comment: Don't you think that these numbers are meaningless ? (Probably the result of concatenation, but where do you split ?)

Comment: @Daweo I'm trying to use xgboost. I would like to have a normal float value, which is `0.00076181`

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm trying to normalise the data. The data I downloaded has that structure.  I'm getting error like this when I try to do arithmetic operation. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'`

Comment: Something like this would work for your data: `df['number'].str.split('.').str[:2].agg('.'.join).astype(float)`

Comment: Check if there are two dots and delete the last one. Although you should solve the problem of the exit with two points.

Comment: @QuangHoang Not all my values have double dots. Only few of them do. Also could you post your comment as an answer. It will be very helpful for pandas newbies. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use **regex** to delete last occurance of dot when string contains two dots. i use also **numpy.float64** to convert string to float64.

Finally you can do like this  :

```
import numpy
import re

list1 = ["0.00076181.1", "0.00076181.2", "0.00076181.3", "0.000761813", "0.1"]
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    if list1[i].count(".") == 2:
        list1[i] = re.sub(r".(\w)$", r"\1", list1[i])
        
print([numpy.float64(i) for i in list1])
```

**Output :**

```
[0.000761811, 0.000761812, 0.000761813, 0.000761813, 0.1]
```

Comment: Yes it is, check my update

Comment: @Timus The code has this check `list1[i].count(".") == 2`. So 0.1 would be skipped.

Comment: @John I know, I had missed that part. Hence my comment is gone ;)

Comment: It is a nonsense to hide the problem without understanding it.